# SQL - distinct number of elements in the row

Tags: mysql, sql

Let’s say I have three columns: dim1, dim2, dim3 - all of int type values.

I want to calculate the number of distinct values in the **row** - so in case for row of ID #13 dim1=20, dim2=30 and dim3=20, the value stored in the newly created column would be equal 2.

Is this possible somehow? I tried various combinations on COUNT DISTINCT on multiple columns, didn’t work so far.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions like `count` work across rows, not columns. I see two ways that you could solve this:

1) You could use case statements to solve this (this solution becomes significantly more complicated with more than 3 fields):

```
select dim1, dim2, dim3,
       case when dim1 <> dim2 then 1 else 0 end
       + case when dim1 <> dim3 then 1 else 0 end
       + case when dim2 <> dim3 then 1 else 0 end as cnt
from your_table
```

2) Assuming you have some kind of ID on each row, you could use `union` to turn your data into more of a key/value set, which would allow you to use `count`:

```
select dim1, dim2, dim3, cnt
from your_table
     join (select id, count(distinct dim) as cnt from
                  (select id, dim1 as dim from your_table
                   union all 
                   select id, dim2 from your_table
                   union all 
                   select id, dim3 from your_table)
           group by id) c
     on your_table.id = c.id
```

Comment: Your first version is counting the duplicates, not the number of distinct.

Comment: @Barmar: You are correct. I've reversed the conditions.

Comment: You need `ELSE 0` in all your `CASE` expressions, otherwise it adds `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (I didn't try however)

```
SELECT row_id,
       CASE WHEN dim1=dim2 THEN CASE WHEN dim1=dim3 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
            WHEN dim1=dim3 OR dim2=dim3 THEN 2
            ELSE 1
       END AS nr_equal
FROM   ....
```

Comment: This is counting the number of duplicates, not the number of distincts.